# Probability of randomly drawing all values from a uniform distribution?

Tags: statistics

How can I find the probability that I will draw *every* element from a uniform distribution by draw number N?

For example, if I have a lottery ball machine with 100 balls and draw balls at random, replacing them after each draw, what is the probability that by a certain draw I have seen all the balls?  Obviously, the probability is 0 until 100 draws, and it never reaches (but approaches) 1.

I'm not even sure the right terminology for this.  I've read about cumulative distribution, but that seems to be the probability that a randomly drawn ball is value N or less.

Comment: This is called the Coupon Collector's Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: @NuclearHoagie ah, it's amazing how just knowing the right name can make things much easier to find!